# Syntax of a Photoshop JSX script to zoom the visual display of an image CS6

Tags: jsx, photoshop

I am trying to create a JSX script to change the visual zoom in Photoshop CS6 to, for instance 50%. It is responding "Error 21 - undefined is not an object" on the line "activeView.zoom = zoomLevel;". I suspect this is because I am on CS6. Please can anyone help me alter the code so it works on Photoshop CS6? (Note, I do not want to change the size of the image to 50%)

```
    if (app.documents.length > 0) {
      var activeView = app.activeDocument.activeView;
      var zoomLevel = 50;
      activeView.zoom = zoomLevel;
    } else {
      alert("No document is currently open.");
    }
```

Comment: [This](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/scripting-for-zoom-and-scroll-in-cc2018/m-p/10048755) might be useful